# C# junk characters break XElement "pretty" representation

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have occasionally run across XML with some junk characters tossed in between the elements, which appears to be confusing whatever internal XNode/XElement method handles prettifying the Element.

The following...

```
var badNode = XElement.Parse(@"<b>+
  <inner1/>
  <inner2/>
</b>"
```

prints out

```
<b>+
  <inner1 /><inner2 /></b>
```

while this...

```
var badNode = XElement.Parse(@"<b>
  <inner1/>
  <inner2/>
</b>"
```

gives the expected

```
<b>
  <inner1 />
  <inner2 />
</b>
```

According to the debugger, the junk character gets parsed in as the XElement's "NextNode" property, which then apparently assigns the remaining XML as *its* "NextNode", causing the single line prettifying.

Is there any way to prevent/ignore this behavior, short of pre-screening the XML for any errant characters in between tag markers?

Comment: youre best bet here is to look at regex.replace on an pattern \ array of characters

Comment: You are seeing that because, by adding the non-whitespace `+` character into the `<b>` element value, the element now contains [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content).  And as soon as that happens, `XmlWriter` will no longer automatically insert whitespace when writing the element.  See the [documentation remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You getting awkward indentation for `badNode` because, by adding the non-whitespace `+` character into the `<b>` element value, the element now contains [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content), which is defined by the W3C as follows:

> **3.2.2 Mixed Content**
>
> [Definition: An element type has **mixed content** when elements of that type may contain character data, optionally interspersed with child elements.]

The presence of mixed content inside an element triggers special formatting rules for [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which is used internally by `XElement.ToString()` to actually write itself to an XML string) that are explained in the [documentation remarks for `XmlWriterSettings.Indent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> This property only applies to [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) instances that output text content; otherwise, this setting is ignored.
>
> The elements are indented as long as the element does not contain mixed content. Once the WriteString or WriteWhitespace method is called to write out a mixed element content, **the XmlWriter stops indenting**. The indenting resumes once the mixed content element is closed.

This explains the behavior you are seeing.

As a workaround, [parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Parse_System_String_System_Xml_Linq_LoadOptions_) your XML with [`LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.loadoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2), which *preserves insignificant white space while parsing*, might be what you want:

```
var badNode = XElement.Parse(@"<b>+
  <inner1/>
  <inner2/>
</b>",          
                             LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
Console.WriteLine(badNode);
```

Which outputs:

```
<b>+
  <inner1 />
  <inner2 />
</b>
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hI10jL).

Alternatively, if you are sure that `badNode` should not have character data, you could strip it manually after parsing:

```
badNode.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Remove();
```

Now `badNode` will no longer contain mixed content and `XmlWriter` will indent it nicely.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/apJmcL).